# Polynomials question that I'm stuck on

Tags: polynomials

A point 2,5 lies on a certain function and it is an odd function. What is the remainder when the function is divided by 2

Comment: What if the point $(2, 0)$ was on the graph instead? Do you know what the remainder would be then?

Comment: Perhaps when you say that a point $(a,b)$ lies on a polynomial $p(x)$, what you mean is that the point lies on the graph of $y=p(x)$, which is to say, $p(a)=b$. Now: do you know a fact about the remainder when you divide a polynomial by $x-c$? Do you know what "odd function" means?

Comment: so the answers -5?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The remainder equals $f(-2)$.

Comment: the answers given are 0,2,5 and negative 5

Comment: @user95126 Read the hint given here as you reflect on the meaning of an "odd function".

Comment: so the answers -5?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: thankyou, I put that in the exam just wanted to check I was right

Comment: You are welcome.